# Easily install a font per language who haven't any yet, on Debian 10

Tags: debian, fonts

Listening to a khmer song on the Internet, I saw that khmer Unicode characters were replaced by squares in my french `Debian` installation. Collecting what else was missing, it was also thaï, nepali... plenty of languages that are not displayed properly.

I am a bit jealous with `Windows` here. How can I install easily all the missing fonts my O.S. lacks to be able to display any page in the world on `Firefox` with it's due characters ?

---

Three questions inside this post :

1. How can I detect all the language "Locale codes" that are lacking a font ?
   en, kh, kr, id, jp... automatically. All the missing ones.
2. How to install their proper fonts.
   If there is a best font for each language, where is the list of the best font per language ?
3. Does anyone wrote in the `Debian` community a script of `apt-get install font..` script with all the fonts needed to ensure that it is able to display a text in any language, like `Windows` can ?

That summarizes in : "*How can I get quickly a browser able to display a text in any language*" easily ? Just that basic and classical `Windows` feature ?

Comment: Is it not possible to add languages under the Options > General > Language menu in Firefox?

Comment: Have you installed the `fonts-khmeros` package?

Comment: @kemotep : no, firefox offers Deja Vu (Sans Serif) for every language.

Comment: @GAD3R I can't choose each font one by one. Is it fonts-thaios for thaï, fonts-indiaos for India ? If my Firefox lacks 100 fonts, I can't find 100 packages names.

Comment: @Marc You could start with the font meta packages. For Thai and Indian there are [xfonts-thai](https://packages.debian.org/buster/xfonts-thai) and [fonts-indic](https://packages.debian.org/buster/fonts-indic).

Comment: For Korean (Hangul) - see [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81553/how-to-add-korean-keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install fonts with character coverage for those scripts. The are two approaches you can take:

- Install fonts specifically targeting the languages you're interested in. Debian has collected a bunch of these into task-«language»*. So, e.g., `task-khmer-desktop` recommends `fonts-khmeros`, so that's a good font to install to get Khmer text to display. Similarly, `task-nepali-desktop` recommends `fonts-lohit-deva`.
- Install fonts targeting global coverage. The `fonts-noto` is one such package. There is also `ttf-unifont` (and the bitmap `unifont` its made from), but that's much lower quality.

There are also some other fonts you might be interested in (e.g., `fonts-ancient-scripts`, `fonts-lg-aboriginal`). And honestly the output of `apt-cache search ^fonts-sil`.

Comment: How can I check how many languages are lacking and automatize installation of packages that have various names ? How can I have `Debian` working like `Windows` that is able to display all the fonts of all the countries immediately, without needing 100 manual `apt-get install fonts-language1os`, `font-langage2deva`, where _os_, _deva_ suffixes aren't prediciales ?

Comment: This answer could highlight how vast are `fonts-noto` and `unifont` and that merely installing any of them solves what was asked, i.e. that Firefox will display all text at https://www.wikipedia.org, which lists all Wikipedia language versions, and similar sites. When I read this answer before, I misconcluded that those are just big font packages, but not big enough, so that installing each font separately is still the primary solution. Learning that LibreOffice bundles Noto made me return to this question. The font could make a Windows user "jealous", speaking in the terms of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flavour of Debian which has preinstalled all fonts which are recommended for every supported language desktop version. It is the live system on the installation media. When you run your Debian from a USB flash drive, it has all the fonts ready because it has configured all supported localisations for desktop. On Debian, you can replicate this by installing `live-task-localisation-desktop` package. The package is not explicitly intended for non-live installation. According to its description:

> This metapackage installs packages and documentation to help support
> Debian  live graphical desktop environments for other languages.

[Michael Biebl reported](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=931788) that if you install Debian using the live installation media for GNOME, all localisation tasks are installed. I also had a similar issue and had it resolved by removing some live packages. It was more than a year ago, but it should still be true for the current 10.5 release. You can use it to your benefit, but it can be considered a bug because it is safe to assume that a regular user will not need localisation for languages that such user has no command of and did not intentionally install. It also may cause inconvenience by cluttering the system.

- For example, the fonts will be displayed as options in LibreOffice
  despite them being unused.
- Fonts take up disk space. It may be an issue for some users.
- Localisation also installs spellchecking support for those languages,
  which leads to further clutter, like too many dictionary options
  in Firefox and Thunderbird.
- Localisation also installs other packages, not all of which are necessary for displaying fonts, such as Debian reference translations.

A solution to the last two could be a metapackage depending on recommended fonts only. At the moment there seems to be no such package. It would be nice to have one, so that all language-specific fonts show up correctly at all Wikipedia pages, for example.

---

You can preview the list of packages, which would be installed if you installed `live-task-localisation-desktop` like this:

```
$ sudo apt install live-task-localisation-desktop --assume-no
```

The fonts packages are grouped together and [their names start with `fonts-`](https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts), so you can just copy them all together and install manually in one run if you wish.

If copied from terminal, you will need to remove new line characters `\n` first. You can do it in `gedit` or a different text editor by running find and replace of `\n` for an empty string.

The list of packages also contains fonts starting with `xfonts-`, but they are bitmap fonts which are mostly intended for use in terminal, so you do not need them for web.